# FormData array.push not working to send to Mongodb & Mongoose CastError: Cast to Array failed for value

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb

I am completely lost to get some ajax form to work my case scenario I want to use a form to collect its data and post it to MongoDB using an Express App, for some reason I am trying to pass an array of sites to the DB but for some reason it's coming as a string with quotes but it won't accept an array of objects.

**My Code:**

```
$("#createClients").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var formData = new FormData(this);
  var siteArr = [];
  $(".site").each(function(){
    var siteUrl = $(this).val();
    var siteObj = {
      "site": siteUrl
    };
    siteArr.push(siteObj);// if I use stringify it returns 2 strings with 2 objects
  });//building array of sites from inputs

  console.log("Sites Array", siteArr);//Here the array looks right and returns all objects from the inteneration

  formData.append('sites', siteArr);

  // here I am appending it to the response but it returns like ["{"site":"site.com"},{"site":"site.com"}"]
  // for some reason its generating quotes for the objects just like a string !!?!?!?

  $.ajax({
    url: "/clients/create",
    type: "POST",
    connection: "keep-alive",
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: formData,
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});// posts new Clients
```

**My Mongoose model:**

```
...
    sites: [],
...
```

**My problems:**

- The **siteObj** is returned from the **formData()** with quotes if I JSON.stringify the object **sites:["{"site":"http://www.site1.com"},{"site":"http://www.site2.co.uk"}"]**.
- If I pass the **siteObj** as a data type it returns **sites:["[object Object],[object Object]"]** as string.

What am I doing wrong here?... Thanks for your response in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some deeper research and another 3 days hammering my own head over this nonsense issue I came to a solution:

**1. Mongoose validation can be done in 2 ways...**

```
...
    sites: [{site: {type: String}}], ... or using a new mongoose Schema 

   const SiteUrls = mongoose.Schema({
    site:  {type: String}
   });

**then...**

sites: [SiteUrls]
...
```

**2. The Ajax method to transfer FormData with appended Array should look like the example below or you will face a validation error from Mongoose "Cast to Array failed for value"...**

```
$("#createClients").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

var formData = new FormData(this);
var siteArr = [];

$(".site").each(function() {
  var siteUrl = $(this).val();
  siteArr.push({'site':siteUrl});
}); //building array of sites from inputs

console.log("Sites Array", JSON.stringify(siteArr)); 

formData.append('sites', JSON.stringify(siteArr));// SEND the array as string otherwise it will send [object object] as the string... this should build a response like [{"url":"site.com"},{"url":"site2.co.uk"}]... follow clients.js file use JSON.parse(req.body.sites); to turn it into a parsed object like so [{url:"site.com"},{url:"site2.co.uk"}]

$.ajax({
  url: "/clients/create",
  type: "POST",
  connection: "keep-alive",
  contentType: false,
  cache: false,
  processData: false,
  data:  formData,
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});


}); // posts new Clients
```

THEN!!!

**3. Clients.js Router**

```
...
sites: JSON.parse(req.body.sites), // turn it into a parsable array so data is validated by mongoose and sent to DB
...
```